# XCode doesn't login to my account

Tags: xcode

I couldn't be able to login to XCode accounts using my apple ID. It was working before. When I tried to login it shows an error **There was an error connecting to Apple ID Server**. But I have logged into the same account from another mac without any issue. Please help me with this. I am using XCode version 8.3.3 [image]

Comment: Try using a different wifi or internet connection. It is usually solved that way.

Comment: Press cmd shift k, restart xcode, then try again.

Comment: @KingCoder11 Thanks for your reply. But that is not working

Comment: @UmarFarooque Thanks for your reply, but its not working

Comment: My date/time was wrong, I fixed it and it worked. What a misleading error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try these basic ways may be it will help full

1. Restart your system,sometimes the simplest turning off and on can
   fix this error directly.
2. Sometimes it happens due to the poor Internet connection, check
   whether connection is working properly.
3. Make sure that the date, time, and time zone are set correctly.
4. [Apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7251304?tstart=0) says you should check your firewall and antivirus settings - there may be
   a similar rule or setting blocking the ID server

Comment: My date/time was wrong, I fixed it and it worked, thanks. What a misleading error message.

Comment: 10.15.1 and we STILL have to reboot the system. Unbelievable. Total recall of MSDOS days :-[

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I upgraded my Xcode and Mac OS to the latest version and it started working smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Charles proxy was the cause for me. Make sure you disable/uncheck HTTP( WebProxy) and HTTPS( Secure Web Proxy) and give it a try